# Setuid bit for root is set but real user id is not 0

Tags: linux, permissions, setuid

My program `permissiontest` has the following privileges:

```
-rwsrwxrwx 1 root root 8664 Nov 18 15:59 permissiontest
```

It consists of the following code when being run as non-root user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("EUID: %d\n", geteuid());
    printf("RUID: %d\n", getuid());
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It outputs:

```
EUID: 1000
RUID: 1000
```

From what I have read about the setuid-bit, I thought the real user id should be 0 when I execute the program because root is the owner of the program. However, the real user id does not seem to be 0.

Can anybody tell me, why this is the case?

The program is on the local hard drive and fstab does not indicate anything, so no mounting issues should be involved.

Comment: is the volume mounted with `nosuid`?

Comment: and is this a sudo-configured system where root is not only disabled, but locked, like ubuntu and its derivatives?

Comment: You might want to use the contact us link to request an account merger. Unregistered accounts suck like that.